# Drupal forms api module - include value from parent node

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7

I've written a simple module using the Drupal 7 forms API which adds a block to Drupal which can then be used on multiple nodes.

I'm a bit lost as to the best way to customise some of the values in (hidden) form fields based on where it's been included.

E.g. the module on the /articles/ may need to have a hidden value to say which mailing list they're signing up to, and the same form on /petitions/ may need a different value.

Is there a more elegant way to do this than using form_alter hooks?

Comment: The only more elegant way would be to put the conditional logic in the form generation function itself - if you're building the form, there's not much point writing another hook to alter it. If you're re-using an existing form, a form alter hook is the only sensible option you have really

Comment: hook_form_alter is exactly what you're supposed to use here